# Parsing the html for something that is clearly there but it is not printing as a result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search.php?org_id=KCBA"
page = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(page, features="lxml")

text_comp_date = doc.find('Frisco BBQ Challenge')
print(text_comp_date)
```

I am searching for "**Frisco BBQ Challenge**" it has b tags

Comment: That page uses javascript to dynamically create page content.  The `requests` module can't handle javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silenium is not required. It's easier and faster use requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

evr_begin = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
evr_end = (datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=1)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
url = "https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search_ol_json.php?" \
      f"otype=TEXT&evr_map_type=2&org_id=KCBA&evr_begin={evr_begin}&evr_end={evr_end}&" \
      "evr_radius=50&evr_type=269&evr_region_type=1"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='lxml')
for event in soup.find_all('div', class_='row'):
    print(event.find('b').getText(), event.find('i').getText())
```

OUTPUT:

```
Frisco BBQ Challenge 6/16/2022 - 6/18/2022
York County BBQ Festival 6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022
Central Plains Ribfest 6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022
Knights Of Columbus BBQ Smoke Off "4 Life" 6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022
Rose Festival 21st Annual KCBS BBQ Contest 6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022
Hoosier BBQ Classic Day 1 6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022
Hoosier BBQ Classic (One Meat Ribs) 6/17/2022 - 6/17/2022
Almost Heaven BBQ Bash 6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022
Central Plains Ribfest (Steak) 6/17/2022 - 6/17/2022
Clay County Juneteenth BBQ Contest (One Meat Ribs) 6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022
BBQ Battle Finland (POSTPONED) 6/18/2022 - 6/19/2022
The War of Barbeque 6/18/2022 - 6/19/2022
Hoosier BBQ Classic Day 2 6/18/2022 - 6/19/2022
The War of Barbeque (ONE MEAT RIBS) 6/18/2022 - 6/18/2022
Columbia Valley Smokeshow 6/24/2022 - 6/26/2022
The Cache Smokeout at the American West Heritage Center (POSTPONED UNTIL 2023) 6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022
Big BBQ Bash 6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022
Heritage Days BBQ Showdown (Day One) 6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022
The Great Lenexa BBQ Battle - Kansas State Championship 6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022
Miles City Cowtown Cookoff 6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022
Lake Murvaul BBQ Cook-Off 6/24/2022 - 6/26/2022
Smokin Deltana BBQ Challenge (POSTPONED) 6/24/2022 - 6/25/2022
Riverland Smokers BBQ Contest 6/25/2022 - 6/26/2022
Second Annual Central Maine BBQ Cookoff 6/25/2022 - 6/26/2022
Heritage Days BBQ Showdown (Day Two) 6/25/2022 - 6/26/2022
Giant National Capital Barbecue Battle 6/25/2022 - 6/26/2022
Central Maine BBQ Cook Off (ONE MEAT RIBS) 6/25/2022 - 6/25/2022
Lowell's Smokin' In the Ozarks-Arkansas State Challenge 7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022
Happy Basset 2nd Annual BBQ Competition 7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022
2nd Annual VFW Post 3396 Armed Forces BBQ Challenge (MASTERS) 7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022
The Art of BBQ 7/1/2022 - 7/2/2022
Twin Smoke 7/2/2022 - 7/3/2022
Sweet Home Icebox Cookoff 2022 7/2/2022 - 7/3/2022
2nd Annual VFW Post 3396 Armed Forces BBQ Challenge (ONE MEAT RIBS) 7/2/2022 - 7/2/2022
Smokin with Weemala (One Meat Chicken) 7/2/2022 - 7/2/2022
Smokin with Weemala (One Meat Ribs) 7/2/2022 - 7/2/2022
South Carolina Festival of Discovery 7/7/2022 - 7/9/2022
Ohio Veterans BBQ Cook-Off (CANCELLED) 7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022
Clayton BBQ Cook-off  7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022
Sand Creek Summer Daze Saucy & Glazed BBQ Competition 7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022
Harvest on Fire at the Winery 7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022
2022 Black Silos Swine in the Vine BBQ Contest (Day 1) 7/8/2022 - 7/9/2022
2022 Black Silos Swine in the Vine BBQ Contest (Day 2) 7/9/2022 - 7/10/2022
New Jersey State Barbecue Championship 7/9/2022 - 7/10/2022
Chillin & Grillin in the Glades 7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022
KTD Smokin Gobbler Cook-off 7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022
KTD Smokin Gobbler Cook-off (One Meat Ribs) 7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022
Bordertown BBQ Brawl 7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022
Bordertown BBQ Brawl (One Meat Ribs) 7/15/2022 - 7/15/2022
Central Illinois BBQ Throwdown 7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022
Central Illinois BBQ Throwdown (One Meat Ribs) 7/15/2022 - 7/15/2022
2022 Cameron Elks BBQ Cook Off (Day 1) 7/15/2022 - 7/16/2022
enter code here
```

Comment: could you explain why your url is different? Otherwise this is great thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. I used the developer tool in the browser (called by the f12 key, then go to the network tab) and figured out which request gives the necessary information(ctrl + f on network tab, and past 'Frisco BBQ Challenge', it pointed me to the requested query ). 
If you look at the parameters in this link, you can change them to whatever you need to make this method more versatile. I hope I explained clearly

Comment: can i ask you another question pertaining to the html?

Comment: @ClayH of course yes

Answer (score 0):

*Try using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) to automate the browser, I'm using Firefox here*

*Example*

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search.php?org_id=KCBA"

with webdriver.Firefox() as firefox_browser:
    firefox_browser.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(2)
    html = firefox_browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    elements = soup.select("#updated-events-container > div:nth-child(2)")
    print(elements)

    for element in elements:
        print(element.text)
```

*Make sure to install [browser driver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/)*